# How to Scroll a `child: Column` on Flutter using AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My aim is to implement a scroll on a page where overscrolls will be clamped by default. This is implemented by the `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics` class on `flutter`, but I am not being able to find proper resource regarding its implementation.

Below is my code of one of the pages where I would like to implement this - but do note that I am facing complications regarding the scroll ability of this. I have tried `Scrollable` and `SingleChildScrollView`, with both giving error "too many positional arguments"). The problem with that, to the best of my understanding - is that I am using a column to implement this, which is not the right manner.

Any kind of help or pointers regarding the whole issue would be much appreciated.

```
body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Header(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Some Exam',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'GoogleMedium',
                    color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
            Subject(
              iconData: OMIcons.supervisorAccount,
              title: 'English',
              msg: 'Difficulty Level: Easy',
              count: '145',
              colors: Color(0xff1a73e8),
            ),

            Subject(
              iconData: OMIcons.forum,
              title: 'Chinese',
              msg: 'Score 25 more to become an expert!',
              count: '475',
              colors: Color(0xff8024cd),
            ),
            Subject(
              iconData: OMIcons.forum,
              title: 'Analytical',
              msg: 'Good improvement!',
              count: '123 in 4 days',
              colors: Color(0xff8024cd),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
              child: Text(
                'ACTIVE FRIENDS',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontFamily: 'GoogleMedium',
                    color: Colors.black54),
              ),
            ),
            activeFriend(
              sender: "Another Name",
              title: "Just an Exam",
              time: "3 seconds ago",
              studied: "Bangla",
            ),
            activeFriend(
              sender: "Difficult Guy",
              title: "An Exam",
              time: "18 minutes ago",
              studied: "Analytical",
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView`, it's only require one child.

```
SingleChildScrollView (
   child: Column( ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked just fine since this now has 1 child only. It somehow skipped me.

Working solution:

  `child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(`